# Binding matTooltip to 2 value

Tags: angular

I have a list that contains lists each contains operations, and I want to apply a tooltip on a precise list, so I did that.

```html
<li *ngFor="let op of opList"
    style="margin-right: 5px;margin-left: 5px;"
    class="elementList">
        <div class="pointer"
            (dblclick)="addOperator(op, myTextArea)" 
            [matTooltip]="opList==repDateOperations ? date1 :null">{{op}}</div>
</li>
```

the `repDateOperations=["RepStartDate","RepEndDate"]`

[image]

I want when I hover on RepStartDate show me the value of a variable date1 and when a I hover on RepEndDate show me the value of other variable date2.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

What you are probably looking for is :

```
*ngFor="let op of opList; let i = index"
[matTooltipDisabled]="opList !== repDateOperations"
[matTooltip]="i === 0 ? data1 : data2"
```